# Server communication with database

Tags: database, unity-game-engine, server, client

I'm creating an online game and the client is going to be made using unity as well as the server and I'm wondering whether it's okay for the server to communicate with mysql database via PHP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**For simple tasks, there is actually nothing wrong with that.**

There is also a example of using this method in the wiki here: http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php?title=Server_Side_Highscores

*But be aware: that is not the fastest solution.*

You could make a faster direct connection with a plugin like this one:
https://github.com/Hanslen/Unity-with-MYSQL

And for native unity support on **Android and iOS** support i would go with a **sqlite database** plugin: https://github.com/rizasif/sqlite-unity-plugin

Comment: Thank you for the answer :) and also for the links, will consider the second one